# Displaying custom font icon code in Swift dynamically

Tags: swift, fonts, swiftui

I need to display icons dynamically from a custom font in swift.
The icon format is like: `\u{code}` example: `\u{e054}`.
The dynamic value of the icon contains only the code and doesn't include `\u{` and `}` therefore I need a way to build the string and concatenate things.

I made it working and I can see the icons but only if I hardcode them, so this works and displays the icon:

```
// works and displays and icon something like  
Text("\("\u{e054}")")
  .font(.custom("custom-font", size: 30))
```

But I need to display it dynamically and all the solution below didn't work and displays the bar text but not the icon:

```
// doesn't work and displays \u{e054} instead of the icon
Text("\\u{\(icon_code)}")
  .font(.custom("custom-font", size: 15))
```

```
// also doesn't work and displays \u{e054} instead of the icon
Text( #\u{\#(icon_code)}#)
  .font(.custom("custom-font", size: 15))
```

Comment: What type is `icon_code`?

Comment: Also explain what "didn't work" means.

Comment: updated the question. icon_code is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easy create String extension where you can handle that by converting string to Int code then convert code to unicode character

```
extension String {
    var unicode: String {
        guard let code = UInt32(self, radix: 16),
              let scalar = Unicode.Scalar(code) else {
            return ""
        }
        return "\(scalar)"
    }
}
```

can be used like this:

```
Text("e054".unicode)
  .font(.custom("custom-font", size: 30))
```

Comment: Works! I like the solution! Thank you!

Comment: @AAkrm Im happy that helped! could you please give it a vote up?

Comment: I d like to, but I don't have reputation for it :(
https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your custom font, but having code we can use `Unicode.Scalar` to generate symbol dynamically, like in below demo

[image: demo]

```
var icon_code = 0xe054
var body: some View {
    if let value = Unicode.Scalar(icon_code) {
        Text(value.escaped(asASCII: false))
            .font(.system(size: 60))
    }
}
```

which is equivalent to hardcoded

```
Text("\u{e054}").font(.system(size: 60))
```

and with converter if original input is-a `String`

```
var icon_code = "e054"
var body: some View {
    if let code = Int(icon_code, radix: 16), let value = Unicode.Scalar(code) {
        Text(value.escaped(asASCII: false))
            .font(.system(size: 60))
    }
}
```